# How to build a dictionary for LDA

Tags: dictionary, lda, vocabulary, dirichlet

I've been working on Latent Dirchlet Allocation for 2 weeks and I'm trying to build a dictionary and a train file to try it. I've already tried it with Matlab and gcc by using the Blei's train file, but I have no idea about how to create a dictionary. Could someone help me? 
Thank you 
Andrea